# Null object on retrieval after insertion

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

Using JUnit, I'm trying to test some business logic. I've following statements in my log:

> [EL Fine]: sql: 2015-01-13 19:55:39.369--ClientSession(623375944)--Connection(1559247181)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME (ID_SEQ, ...) VALUES (?, ...)
>       bind => [363, ...]

During the same test, I'm trying to fetch the same record, but getting NullPointerException, with following statement as last statement:

> [EL Fine]: sql: 2015-01-13 19:55:52.976--ServerSession(512108848)--Connection(1285635179)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID_SEQ, ... FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME WHERE (ID_SEQ = ?)
>       bind => [363]

Moreover, when trying to retrieve through parent object, I do get the correct instance but unable to retrieve the same using Id_Seq. Am unable to figure out what is going wrong here; any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the root cause of problem, sharing in case this could help someone:

My method was annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = false)` which was actually starting a new transaction (with another in progress in parallel) and hence resulting in null reference. Changing it to `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)` resolved the issue.

Thanks!